# Power Query - Merge tables - Sum values with conditions

Tags: powerquery, m, excel-365

I'm new to Power Query and I can't figure out how to do the following:

I have two tables

"REQUESTED"

| Date | ReqNumber | Client | SKU | ReqQuantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan-01 | Z10 | 1 | A | 2 |
| Feb-05 | Z11 | 1 | A | 3 |

"SENT"

| Date | Client | SKU | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan-15 | 1 | A | 1 |
| Feb-02 | 1 | A | 3 |
| Mar-10 | 1 | A | 5 |

What I want to achieve is that I want to merfe the tables and allow me to filter by date, showing the corresponding amount requested/sent

For Example:
If I filter dates between Jan-01 / Jan - 31

I should get the following:

"REQUESTED - SENT"

| Date | ReqNumber | Client | SKU | ReqQuantity | SentQuantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan-01 | Z10 | 1 | A | 2 | 1 |

If I filter dates between Jan-01 / Feb - 28

I should get the following:

"REQUESTED - SENT"

| Date | ReqNumber | Client | SKU | ReqQuantity | SentQuantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan-01 | Z10 | 1 | A | 2 | 2 |
| Feb-05 | Z11 | 1 | A | 3 | 2 |

If I filter dates between Jan-01 / Mar- 15

I should get the following:

"REQUESTED - SENT"

| Date | ReqNumber | Client | SKU | ReqQuantity | SentQuantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan-01 | Z10 | 1 | A | 2 | 2 |
| Feb-05 | Z11 | 1 | A | 3 | 3 |

Is this posiible in Power Query?
Thanks!

Comment: Your sample data is confusing.  Do you not record what the req is whenever you send product?  In your sample the client requests qty 3 on 20210101, you send qty 1 on 20210115, and then qty 3 on 20210202.  You sent a qty of 4 against a requested qty of 2.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately that's actually how the warehouse works. Whenever they send a product to a client, the request number is not recorded because they can send products that where not requested or sometimes they create the new request AFTER sending some of the products, the client requested over the phone for example and sent the request a day after)

Comment: Did you like my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question is a simple one that might get passed over because it is simple.

Two tables "Sent" "Requested"...
Merge is under the Home tab.
[image]
Set "Requested" as Left and "Sent" as right. Select date for both.
[image]
In the Sent column click on the expand icon.
[image]